# Declare and use javascript values on the fly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I have a links which are generated on the fly as shown below:

```
<a href="#" id="btn_0">Data1</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_1">Data2</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_2">Data3</a>
```

I want to use the function below anytime one of the links are clicked on:

```
function alert_some(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

Because of the **restriction on the Chrome Extension impose on inline event handlers**, I can't call the function `alert_some()` from the generated links.

Any idea how I can solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/selom/wxnDj/

Comment: What can't you do, really? Place `" onclick=stuff() "` on the html for the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery with your chrome extension

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "a", function() {
   alert_some($(this).attr("id"));
}

function alert_some(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Or pure JS

```
document.onclick = function(ele) {
    if (ele.originalTarget.localName == "a") {
        alert_some(ele.originalTarget.id);
    }
}

function alert_some(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

This will work with all `a` elements, including those generated on the fly

You will need to discriminate from other `a`s on your page though...
Example `<a href="#" id="btn_2" class="generated">Data3</a>`

---

Or your modified fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wxnDj/36/

Comment: you might need to verify that things like originalTarget, localName work on chrome, if not, find the equivalents.

Comment: It will grab all `a` elements of the page, not only the ones he generated.

Comment: yeah ? so he will need to add a extra test. ``<a href="#" id="btn_2" class="generated">Data3</a>``

Comment: Sweet! I have added a class to specify the exact link I want need to work with. Thanks

Comment: I just modified your fiddle, might be more inline with what you where originally doing. See end of my answer. Otherwise ``jQuery(document).on("click", "a.generated", function() {`` will do the trick just fine

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery#on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to listen to the click event of a link that's added to the DOM whenever.

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function() {
    alert_some($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rotev/wxnDj/34/